# react.js rendering image tag from a function

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, rendering, frontend, bar-chart

I have a bar chart created with d3.js and am trying to display an image tag for each tick in x axis. For example,

```
class Test extends Component {

constructor(props) {

  super(props);
  this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  this.renderAxis = this.renderAxis.bind(this);
 }

componentDidMount() {

  this.setState({
     data: [
             {
               name: 'hello',
               imgUrl: 'https://img.com/someImageUrl',
               value: 100
              },
             {
               name: 'ola',
               imgUrl: 'https://img.com/someImageUrl2,
               value: 50
              }
           ]
        })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){

       this.renderAxis();
    }

   renderAxis() {

        this.x.domain(this.state.dummyData.map( d => d.name )) // <-- this one works

        this.x.domain(this.state.dummyData.map( d => {
        return (
            <img src={d.imgUrl} style={{'width': '30px'}}/> 
        )
    })); // <-- this one does not work

    this.y.domain([0, 100]);

...
```

So above is my code and I believe you already know what I am trying to do.
I thought the way I did would render the image instead of plain text as tick labels, but.. 
How should I render that image tag in this case ..?

Comment: Did you try to call renderAxis from your render function?

Comment: yes, but it does not seem to work.